# IfNull with Zero value is Boolean False. How to count?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

EDIT : more explicit exemple

I would like to count the number of values of one specific field in a collection.

```
chosenSensors = ["CO2_BUR_NE_I_001", "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001"]

match = {'$match':{'$or':list(map(lambda x:{x:{'$exists': True}}, chosenSensors))}}

group = {'$group':{'_id':{'year':{'$year':'$timestamp'}}}}

project = {'$project':{}}

for chosenSensor in chosenSensors:
    group['$group'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] = {'$sum':{'$cond':[{'$ifNull':['$'+chosenSensor, False]}, 1, 0]}}
project['$project'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] = True


sort = {'$sort': {"_id":1}}

pipeline = [match, group, project, sort]

for doc in client["cleanData"]["test"].aggregate(pipeline):
    print(doc)
```

Just below is one sample of my collection. I would like to count the number of values in *CO2_BUR_NE_I_001.*

I expect to have a count of 4.

[image: example with 0]

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226fd"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:36:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226fe"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:37:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226ff"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:38:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab63a1ccb9b0c0fb3d3e5"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-01T19:26:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1080
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb22700"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:39:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6025ccb9b0c0fb226fd"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:36:00.000Z"),
    "TEM_ETG_001" : 1210
}
```

But I have **3**. The value **0** of *CO2_CEL_SE_I_001* is not counted as an existing value.

```
{'_id': {'year': 2016}, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Count': 3, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Count': 5}
```

If I replace **0** by **880** in the involved document...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226ff"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:38:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}
```

... I find the expected result

```
{'_id': {'year': 2016}, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Count': 4, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Count': 5}
```

EDIT : Beggining of an answer...

When I use $ifNull on a value which exists, it returns the value. However, when this value is 0, it returns 0. But this return is given to $cond, and when it's 0, the $cond is considered as False and it returns 0 instead of 1 to my $sum. How can i handle that?

Comment: The field "always" exists. Surely you mean "count if greater than 0" instead. Hence [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) rather than `$ifNull`

Comment: My question isn't good. I will try to figure out how I can improve it.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've edited my question. I have one part of the answer. When I use $ifNull on a value which exists, it returns the value. However, when this value is 0, it returns 0. But this return is given to $cond, and when it's 0, the $cond is considered as False and it returns 0 instead of 1 to my $sum. How can i handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method uses the fact than Null is lower than numbers (int, doubles, long) in the comparison order of BSON types values : 
[Documentation : comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/#comparison-sort-order)

So I just have to compare my value with None.

```
{'$sum':{'$cond':[{ '$gt': ['$'+chosenSensor, None]}, 1, 0]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Counting the number of values of one specific field in a collection.**

You can use [db.collection.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db-collection-distinct) to get distinct values from mongodb and then find length of list no need of aggregation.

```
values = db.collection.distinct('field',{Conditions})
print(len(values))
```

Comment: But this would only return a single time the document with same values which is not what I want because it would count only once some identical values.